# Eclipse Auto-Import Android Not Working

Tags: android, eclipse, import, android-library

So, I have created an Android Library project for my apps. And I can't auto import the things I need with Eclipse when I am using this library, but when I import them manually it works. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting Eclipse and cleaning the project! Woked for me!